# (Node.js) Need to split big numbers into smaller numbers no larger than 100

Tags: node.js, numbers

I have no idea how to google this, so I thought I'd ask here instead.
Due to limitations in a node package I'm using, I need my code to detect if an inputed number is greater than 100, and separate it into smaller numbers, no larger than 100. So if the inputed number is, for example, 264, it would be split into 3 numbers, 100, 100, and 64. Is there a way to this? If so, please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just repeatedly subtract off the factor until you have a number less than the factor:

```js
function splitNum(num, factor) {
    let results = [];
    while (num > factor) {
        results.push(factor);
        num -= factor;
    }
    if (num !== 0) {
        results.push(num);
    }
    return results;
}

console.log(splitNum(264, 100));
```